# Pass Drawable to iTextPdf instead of an Image - Android

Tags: android, image, android-resources, itextpdf

I am using iTextPdf to create a check-in application. I've added the an image already using the image object :

```
imagePath = "/sdcard/Mugshot.jpg";
Image image = Image.getInstance(imagePath);
image.setAbsolutePosition(165f, 465f);
image.scaleToFit(290f,290f);
document.add(image);
```

I would prefer to add the image in the same way before adding any content, as I expect any subsequent stuff would write over existing stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the [API Documentation of iTextPdf](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/Image.html#getInstance(byte[])) you can also contruct using byte[] array

**Convert drawable to `byte[]`**

```
Drawable d = getResources ().getDrawable (R.drawable.your_drawable)
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)d).getBitmap();
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
byte[] bitmapData = stream.toByteArray();
```

**Then**

```
Image image = Image.getInstance(bitmapData);
```

Comment: I'm getting a method undefined error on getResources(). Suggestions?

Comment: if you are not in activity then use `context.getResources()`

Comment: It is a separate class called FileOperations which does reading and writing into the pdf. When i try to make a context (Context context = this; ) , I get a type mismatch error because it isnt an activity.

Comment: use whatever context instance you have,

Comment: Could you be more specific? Can I use any activity's context? If so, how?

Comment: if you are setting this image from an activity then create a parameterized method to pass activity context to anywhere

Comment: I am not SETTING it. I am document.ADDING it in the same FileOperations.java class, which isn't an activity, just a helper class.